# TypeScript and Webpack 4, Module Build failed: Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs, webpack-4

I’ll warn you right away, I’ve already read all similar questions

My babel config in `package.json`:

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "useBuiltIns": "usage"
        }
      ],
      [
        "@babel/preset-react",
        {
          "useSpread": true,
          "development": true
        }
      ],
      [
        "@babel/preset-typescript",
        {
          "allExtensions": true
        }
      ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
        {
          "loose": true,
          "useBuiltIns": true
        }
      ]
    ],
    "env": {
      "production": {
        "plugins": [
          "@babel/proposal-class-properties"
        ]
      }
    }
```

My webpack config:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = (env = {}) => {
    const {
        mode = 'development'
    } = env;

    const isProd = mode === 'production';
    const isDev = mode === 'development';

    const getStyleLoaders = () => {
        return [
            isProd ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader',
            'css-loader'
        ];
    };

    const getPlugins = () => {
        const plugins = [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'server', 'templates', 'index.html')
            }),
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env': {
                    BROWSER: true,
                    API_ROOT: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_ROOT || '')
                }
            }),
        ];

        if (isProd) {
            plugins.push(new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: 'main-[hash:8].css'
            }));
        }

        return plugins;
    };

    return {
        entry: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'app', 'components', 'App.js')
        ],
        mode: isProd ? 'production' : isDev && 'development',
        output: {
            filename: 'main-[hash:5].js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'assets'),
        },

        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader"
                    }
                },
                // Loading CSS
                {
                    test: /\.(css)$/,
                    use: getStyleLoaders()
                },

                // Loading SASS/SCSS
                {
                    test: /\.(sss)$/,
                    use: [...getStyleLoaders(), 'sass-loader']
                },
            ]
        },
        plugins: getPlugins(),
        devServer: {
            hot: true,
            stats: {
                colors: true
            }
        }
    };
};
```

When trying to build an assembly, the following error occurs:

```
ERROR in ./app/components/App.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /home/cpt/Desktop/novaya/dev/app/components/App.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (70:5)

  68 |          const ZoomInAndOut = ({ children, position, ...props }) => (
  69 |                  <Transition
> 70 |                    {...props}
     |                    ^
  71 |                    timeout={800}
```

I cannot understand what my configuration is missing. I tried several different options, everywhere this error.
I use the latest (currently 2020.04.02) versions of all npm packages

UPD:  a new error has occurred: https://prnt.sc/qxf0pt

Comment: You are trying to use Typescript syntax in JS file, remove `: any` and `: void`

Comment: @RafalLesniak I need to keep Typescript. But thanks for the tip

Comment: try renaming the file to `App.ts` or use `allExtensions: true` as mention here https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript

Comment: @AneesMuhammed It helped, thanks! But another error occurred https://prnt.sc/qxf0pt

Comment: @A.Burdonskaya What is your babel version ? can you try using this https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread?

Comment: `"@babel/core": "7.8.4"`

Comment: Why do you use .js to write typescript code? Is inconsistent. Keep good practices event at beginning of your journey with coding

Comment: @RafalLesniak this is not my code, I just need to update webpack

Comment: @A.Burdonskaya did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @kibin unfortunately no

Comment: @A.Burdonskaya for me it was pain in the arse to find out, but simple in the end to fix. I used flow-to-ts to convert all the files in out project to typescript, and the one which gave me that error was wrongly converted to .ts extension, as it contained jsx. I renamed it to .tsx and it helped. So maybe extension is what causes your problems. Try to rename files to .jsx or .tsx and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of `preset` like this

```
 "presets": [
      ["@babel/preset-env", {"useBuiltIns": "usage"}],
      "@babel/preset-react",
      "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
```